# Why do Angular Locale defintiition files do not match locale identifiers for registerLocaleData

Tags: angular, internationalization

I am trying to call RegisterLocaleData with locale data dynamically loaded from angular framework using locale identifiers but have been unable to do this due to framework naming conventions.

I have written a function like:

```
public importLocaleDataAndSetLocaleFor(locale: string): Promise<void> {
   return import(`@angular/common/locales/${locale}.js`)
      .then((localeModule) => {
          registerLocaleData(localeModule.default, locale);
   });
}
```

When the locale Identifier is 'en-GB' then it will successfully work. (file exists)
When the locale identifier is 'de-DE' then it will not. (file not exists)

Why do the locale files not exist for these locales in the Angular framework? It seems wrong/unusal given the identifiers are a standard.

Surley there should be a file for common/locales/en-gb

Surley there should be a file for common/locales/en-US

Surley there should be a file for common/locales/de-DE

But there are files for common/locales/en.js but that doesn't make sense. How can a locale file have a language but no region?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out after some poking and going to share, as it seem unintuitive:

According to [this post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20340#issuecomment-343865420):

- if a locale is the most used for a language, it becomes the default parent locale, for example "en" is equivalent to "en-US".
- if a regional locale is equivalent to the parent locale, then this regional locale is no longer listed (as it would be a duplicate), that's why you only have "en" and not "en-US", the same for french where you have "fr" but not "fr-FR"
- *the default parent locale is not always equivalent to the country of origin of a language, for example "pt" for Portuguese is actually Brazilian Portuguese and not Portuguese as spoken in Portugal because there are more people speaking Brazilian Portuguese. That's why you don't have a "pt-BR" locale, but you have a "pt-PT" locale (since pt-PT !== pt).

As a result the following syntax will reliably dynamically resolve the filename from a given locale identifier.

```
public importLocaleDataAndSetLocaleFor(locale: string): Promise<void> {

return import(`@angular/common/locales/${locale}.js`)
  .then(
    localeModule => {
      registerLocaleData(localeModule.default, locale);
      this.lang = locale;
    },
    () => {
      const fallbackLocale = locale.split('-')[0];
      return import(`@angular/common/locales/${fallbackLocale}.js`)
        .then(fallbackLocaleModule => {
          registerLocaleData(fallbackLocaleModule.default, fallbackLocale);
          this.lang = locale;
        });
    }
  );
}

private registerLocaleDataWith(localeModule: any, locale: string): void {
   registerLocaleData(localeModule.default, locale);
   this.lang = locale;
}
```